# Windows 8 Color Settings (Window Title)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, themes, windows-8, visual-styles

In Windows 7, the window title's color (by default black, to see the title in the title bar fire up Windows Media Player for example) is stored in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors]` `TitleText` value.

This is not the case in Windows 8, since this value is only used when using high contrast theme.

It looks like noone has come up with a way to change this color yet, so my question is, where to look? What tools can I use to see dependencies, what could be the way to find this value (I rightfully hope it's not a constant in code).

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution here: http://www.eightforums.com/customization/8724-windows-8-desktop-ui-change-title-text-color.html

However it's very much use at your own risk.

> This is an at your own Risk tutorial Create a Restore Point
>
> Then, go here
>
> [Dark theme for Windows8 RTM by ~Nighthawk-F22 on deviantART](http://nighthawk-f22.deviantart.com/art/Dark-theme-for-Windows8-RTM-324474705)
>
> Then you will also need this,
>
> [Homepage M. Hoefs - Software](http://www.syssel.net/hoefs/software_uxtheme.php?lang=en#down)
>
> Run the UXTheme Patcher
>
> Will patch the following files and append .backup to the originals...
>
> uxinit.dll uxtheme.dll themeui.dll
>
> If you uninstall UXThemePatcher it is supposed to replace the original
>   files back.
>
> Then try to copy the files from the Visual Style in the first link (I
>   used Theme Without Thin White Inline Frame) to
>   C:\Windows\Resources\Themes
>
> And overwrite the files.
>
> If you have to take Ownership of the Themes folder, that is fine and
>   then give Full Admin Rights to it and child objects. DO NOT TAKE
>   OWNERSHIP OF THE SYSTEM32 FOLDER as a whole, or even your C: drive.
>   ONLY the Themes folder. You have been warned.
>
> You may have to reboot a couple of times, Also, when you change themes
>   the first time, Windows may freak out, but just reboot and it should
>   be OK. Otherwise, you may have to do a restore and try again.