# Windows 8.1 custom title bars

Tags: colors, windows-8.1, visual-styles

How do i set custom colors for active and inactive title bars, Windows 2000-style, in Windows 8.1?

I do not want to enable high contrast mode, because it makes Internet Explorer unusable.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/470733/windows-8-color-settings-window-title) and the linked thread? Maybe it has some useful tips.

Comment: @Karan sorry, nothing of use to me there.

Comment: Have a look as well into [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/594721/8672) requiring switching to the Aero Lite style themes.

Comment: If a commercial product is acceptable, you could try [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) ($7.49, trial available).

Comment: @harrymc I know how to change the text color, i want to change the bar color too.

Comment: I suggest the trial version of WindowBlinds - if it can't do it then this is just plain impossible.

Comment: @harrymc I indicated that i want a solution that does not require admin rights.

Comment: I suggested this as a test, because I'm not sure that a solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it easily - not a feature provided by Microsoft. However there are couple of options for you:

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors/497768#497768) is probably the best one based on your requirements

[Second option](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/169469-title-bar-text-and-background-in-windows-81/), which is not exactly what you are asking for but could still help

Comment: -1 would be better as comment

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of getting under-voted, this is the answer according to my knowledge :

In Windows 8.1, registry options are available only for high contrast themes.
Therefore your only option is to customize a high contrast theme and make it less ugly.

Some third-party tools will help you with that task, for example [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)
($7.49, trial available).

Comment: -1 Please do not give non-answers, this is a bounty question.

Comment: Asking us to rewrite Windows is not acceptable, even with a bounty. Please don't under-vote people who just try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Classic theme for instance:
https://superuser.com/a/844417/152134

[image]