# How to change the title color of programs in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, fonts, colors, desktop-customization

I would like to change the color of the window title text on:

- Windows 8 Professional x64
- With all Aero features enabled
- On the **desktop** (not in MUI mode)

Have tried various existing solutions for Windows 7 Aero and they don't work on Windows 8. Is there any way to do this on Windows 8?

The red ellipse in the below screenshot was added by me; clearly, it is not part of the actual UI. I just wanted to draw attention to the actual text whose color I want to change (ideally, without changing text elsewhere in the operating system, besides window text!)

[image: notepad title]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify single colors when you switch to the **Aero Lite** style themes.

To do that, you need to export a theme (preferably the one you're currently using). The `.themepack` files are actually CAB files and can be edited like those (simply change the file extension or add `.cab` at the end of it). They will contain a `.theme` file which is actually an INI.

Find the **VisualStyles** section and change the **Path** property:

```
[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\AeroLite.msstyles
```

If you apply that theme now, you will see some changes to the UI already, which are most likely undesirable. But I wanted to show this approach anyway.

You can now set the colors in the same `.theme` file, like so:

```
[Control Panel\Colors]
InactiveTitleText=20 20 20
TitleText=0 128 255
```

[image]

`.theme` files can be applied to the system by simply processing them with the default application assigned to the file type.

Comment: On Windows 10, this only seems to change the title color for Explorer windows. Any other application windows are ignored.