# Change Taskbar AND Window Title Text On Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, fonts, colors, desktop-customization

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/594705/change-window-title-text-on-windows-8) shows how to change window title text color. But there is one problem: Aero Lite theme changes taskbar text color to black. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Sure modify the color used in the theme file per the directions.

Comment: Which entry under [Control Panel\Colors] section correspond to taskbar text color? I couldn't find it.

Comment: **WindowText** - http://www.eightforums.com/customization/8724-windows-8-desktop-ui-change-title-text-color.html

Comment: I set WindowText to 255 255 255 but taskbar text color remains black. The text color in all input boxes however became white so I'm typing this blindly :). As per [this link](http://www.debbiesthemes.com/utilities/color_scheme.html) WindowText correspond to "Window field text, inset area text & msg box."

Answer (score -2):

Scroll down to High Contrast Theme and have fun changing the colors!

Source: [How To Enable Aero Glass-Style Transparency in Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/128630/how-to-enable-aero-glass-style-transparency-in-windows-8/)